# Existe alguma forma de esconder o Ajax em uma aplicação web?

Tags: javascript, ajax, aplicação-web

Existe alguma forma de esconder o AJAX em uma aplicação web?

Até que ponto o AJAX é seguro? Pois analisando o código dá pra saber o endereço do servidor, o arquivo, a função, e até mesmo a resposta do servidor...

Answer (score 4):

Não há como "esconder" o AJAX, afinal, não há nada de diferente entre ele e uma requisição comum que o seu navegador faz, exceto o fato de que ele é assíncrono.

Qualquer requisição que você faz é passível de inspeção, seja através da aba *[Network do Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/?hl=pt-br)*, softwares como o [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) e outros. Desse modo, você sempre poderá verificar dados como:

- A URL da requisição;
- Os dados e cabeçalhos enviados;
- O cabeçalho e resposta recebidos;
- E diversas outras informações. É até possível inspecionar o fluxo de dados de um WebSocket em tempo real!

Não considero que isso seja um problema de segurança, afinal, é assim que o HTTP funciona. Você deve se preocupar em tomar cuidado com o que você envia para o cliente e se você está tratando ou não o que ele envia para o servidor.